# Curl in PHP like a Real Browser Still Detected as a Bot

Tags: php, php-curl

So I'm trying to just get the HTML from a page. I have added any possible data into  curl headers SSL anything. But they still know that its a CURL BOT. How can I bypass this or how they do it?
When I visit other pages from them I dont get Detected as a Bot only when I'm on search

```
$url = "https://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/search.html?damageUnrepaired=NO_DAMAGE_UNREPAIRED&isSearchRequest=true&maxPowerAsArray=PS&minPowerAsArray=PS&scopeId=C";
$data = curl($url);
echo $data;
function curl($url, $post = "") {
        $cookie = "cookie.txt";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('authority: suchen.mobile.de', 'path: /fahrzeuge/search.html?damageUnrepaired=NO_DAMAGE_UNREPAIRED&isSearchRequest=true&maxPowerAsArray=PS&minPowerAsArray=PS&scopeId=C', 'scheme: https', 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8', 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br', 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9', 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1'));
        $data = curl_exec ($ch);
        if (curl_error($ch))
            return "Bad";
        if (curl_getinfo($ch)["http_code"] == 200)
            return $data;
}
```

Comment: I did a normal get request with Postman and it worked without a hitch? what's your response?

Comment: I'm getting are u a Human? and contains a Robot Captcha
And when I visit it normally I can see search results..
How u sended Postman request

Comment: I dont know how Postman works. But in PHP or C is not working. I did anything. and I get a Bot Response. You can see the response in here.
https://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/details.html?id=268653330